# Can Windows Server 2003 DHCP Server assign multiple IP Addresses to a single host?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, subnet, dhcp-server

I have Windows 2003 Server handling DHCP for our network. We use reservations to assign some hosts IP addresses. Is it possible for the server to assign a single host two IP addresses in different networks (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24 and 10.10.151.0/16) simultaneously?

Comment: How's the host communicating with the two different networks - are they different interfaces, different vlans, or just multiple subnets in the same broadcast domain?

Comment: If the host has multiple network interfaces then it is possible. Is this a hypothetical question or do you have a specific scenario where this is needed or is currently occurring?

Comment: @joeqwerty If he doesn't have a specific example, I do.  I'm kind of curious as to his specific reason for asking this, but it's caused problems for me recently due to the mind-bogglingly convoluted "design" of the network at some of our manufacturing plants.  (Or, probably, the complete lack of any design effort that went into mashing together various networking equipment into something that vaguely resembles a network.)

Comment: We are transitioning from 192.168.1.0/24 to 10.10.0.0/16 but for a couple of reasons, this can't be done all at once. This would be a temporary measure. In our case, to begin testing, it would be helpful for some of our fixed machines that receive addresses via reservation to get an IP in both ranges (which can be done to a single interface manually on each machine, which I'd like to avoid doing). Assume a router is available to both subnets. I'm sorry for disappearing for 3 months - I thought I had email notifications on for this post but apparently not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows DHCP server doesn't track anything about the "state" of a host to which it assigns an IP address. If the DHCP server receives DHCP requests from the same MAC address in two different subnets (presumably with one or both relayed through a DHCP relay agent) it will issue leases for that MAC in both subnets.

(The same MAC address making multiple requests in the same subnet, which would be the same DHCP scope, is a different story. In that case, the same address would be assigned for all the requests because it's just the same host requesting an IP out of the same scope.)

How you get a network interface to issue two DHCP requests from the same MAC in different subnets (VLANs, etc) is your problem, but the DHCP server won't "care".